# Why isn't my macro functioning in the same way as handwritten code?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

So I have 2 `router` functions for learning to work with `clack` in common lisp. One is written without macros, and the other is written with macros that expand to match the first function, but only the non-macro version is working. The code below has `(:use :trivia)` from `(ql:quickload 'trivia)`.

This one is written without any macros, and works:

```lisp
(defun router (env)
  (match env
    ((guard (property :path-info path)
        (equalp "/" path))
     (home env))
    ((guard (property :path-info path)
        (equalp "/live/clicked" path))
     (live-clicked env))
    ((property :path-info path)
     `(404 nil (,(format nil "404 page not found"))))))
```

I decided I didn't like those guard clauses taking up so much space in the function definition, so I rewrote the function:

```lisp
(defun router (env)
  (match env
    (route "/" (home env))
    (route "/live/clicked" (live-clicked env))
    ((property :path-info path)
     `(404 nil (,(format nil "404 page not found"))))))
```

`route` is defined as so:

```lisp
(defmacro route (valid-path &body body)
  (let ((path (gensym)))
    `((guard (property :path-info ,path)
         (equalp ,valid-path ,path))
      ,@body)))
```

With this new router function and macro, the function is always short-circuiting on the first clause. When macroexpanding the 2 `(route ...)` clauses, I receive this output, matching the function I wrote:

```lisp
* `(defun router (env)
      (match env
        ,(macroexpand '(route "/" (home env))) 
        ,(macroexpand '(route "/live/clicked" (live-clicked env)))
        ((property :path-info path)
         `(404 nil (,(format nil "404")))))))
(DEFUN ROUTER (ENV)
  (MATCH ENV
   ((GUARD (PROPERTY :PATH-INFO #:G120) (EQUALP "/" #:G120)) (HOME ENV))
   ((GUARD (PROPERTY :PATH-INFO #:G121) (EQUALP "/live/clicked" #:G121)) (LIVE-CLICKED ENV))
   ((PROPERTY :PATH-INFO PATH) `(404 NIL (,(FORMAT NIL "404")))))
```

`(home env)` and `(live-clicked env)` are functions that return something similar to `(backquote (200 nil (,(*form generating html*))))`. `env` is the state of the web request, but in this instance it only needs to be `(list :path-info "/live/clicked")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern matcher you are using, Trivia, has a `defpattern` macro. That's what you must use to define a macro against the pattern language itself, rather than `defmacro`.

Comment: I wrote a much longer answer, but it was TL; DR.  The gist of it is that embedded languages provided by macros are not traversed for macroexpansion. The macro-expander sees `match`, and calls a macro. That macro traverses the `match` form and spits out code. That code, though traversed by the expander, no longer has clause syntax for it to look at.  Sub-languages for pattern matching, looping and whatever else must always provide their own macro definers.   Wrapping the constructs is a stop-gap solution that will not scale to multiple developers who all want to extend the same construct.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, [`macroexpand`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm) should be
used for *interactive debugging* rather than in *production code*.
Its use inside `defun` (almost) never makes sense.

Second, to understand your second `router`, you should macroexpand its *body*
rather than the `defun`, i.e.,

```
(macroexpand '(match env
        (route "/" (home env))
        (route "/live/clicked" (live-clicked env))
        ((property :path-info path)
         `(404 nil (,(format nil "404"))))))
```

You will see that `route` is not expanded because it is not in a "function position".

What you need to *expand* your `route` *before* `match` is expanded, i.e., you probably want a
wrapper around `match` (I removed `gensym` because you indicated in the comments that it is really
not necessary):

```
(defmacro my-match (what &body clauses)
  (labels ((handle-clause (clause)
             (if (eq (car clause) 'route)
                 (apply #'route (rest clause))
                 clause))
           (route (valid-path &rest body)
             `((guard (property :path-info path)
                      (equalp ,valid-path path))
               ,@body)))
    `(match ,what ,@(mapcar #'handle-clause clauses))))
```

and then

```
(defun router (env)
  (my-match env
    (route "/" (home env))
    (route "/live/clicked" (live-clicked env))
    ((property :path-info path)
     `(404 nil (,(format nil "404 page not found"))))))
```

Testing:

```
(macroexpand '(my-match env
        (route "/" (home env))
        (route "/live/clicked" (live-clicked env))
        ((property :path-info path)
         `(404 nil (,(format nil "404"))))))
==>
(MATCH ENV ((GUARD (PROPERTY :PATH-INFO PATH) (EQUALP "/" PATH)) (HOME ENV))
 ((GUARD (PROPERTY :PATH-INFO PATH) (EQUALP "/live/clicked" PATH))
  (LIVE-CLICKED ENV))
 ((PROPERTY :PATH-INFO PATH) `(404 NIL (,(FORMAT NIL "404")))))
T
```

Comment: In my code, there's a * before that containing the `macroexpand` calls, signifying that it is in the repl (IE, debugging). I had added `gensym` in debugging attempts, as I was thinking that the `path` variable might be contributing to the issues. I think you could have used kinder phrasing with both of those notes. 

I appreciate your help in this :)

Comment: I am not sure where the you found unkindness, but I apologize nevertheless. I modified the related parts, I hope it's okay now.

Comment: All good - I didn't think you meant anything by it, just rubbed me the wrong way. I've definitely been on the other end of things :). context for future readers, It was noted that I didn't need gensym in my macro.